# Create document library from template with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, list-template

I'm attempting to create a document library from a `.stp` template. 
To my knowledge the script worked and now its not. I get an error when the following is executed:

```
$ListCreation.ListTemplate = $ListTemplate
```

> Exception setting "ListTemplate": "Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplate" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplate" to type 
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplate"."

I thought it may be the that I've referenced the wrong dll's .

Have re-installed:

1. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll v 16.0.6518.1200
2. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable.dll v 16.0.6518.1200

Any ideas on the error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could re-install the [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=42038) and [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=35588).

And there is a demo for your reference  to create the document library from custom template by PnP PowerShell.

```
$username = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "password"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

$Url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/tst" # URL of the site
$ListTemplateInternalName = "TestLibTemplate.stp" # Change this with your own list template
$ListName = "NewLibBaseonTemplate2" # Change this with the name of the list to be created

# Create list from template

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Url -Credentials $cred

$Context = Get-PnPContext
$Web = $Context.Site.RootWeb
$ListTemplates = $Context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($Web)
$Context.Load($Web)
$Context.Load($ListTemplates)
Invoke-PnPQuery 

$ListTemplate = $ListTemplates | where { $_.InternalName -eq $ListTemplateInternalName }

if ($ListTemplate -eq $null)
{
    Throw [System.Exception] "Template not found"
}

$ListCreation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$ListCreation.Title = $ListName
$ListCreation.ListTemplate = $ListTemplate

$Web.Lists.Add($ListCreation)
Invoke-PnPQuery 

Disconnect-PnPOnline
Write-Host "Script complete"
```

Comment: Hi, Thats virtually the same code I am using. Same error persists.

Comment: Did you re-install the SharePoint Online Client Components SDK and SharePoint Online Management Shell?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code I can't be sure of the error message, but here's how I did it:

```
$Installed=Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" }
if ($Installed -eq $null) { Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" }

$SourceWebURL="http://<URL of site>"
$SourceWeb=Get-SPWeb -Identity $SourceWebURL
$NewLibrary="<Library Name>"
$TemplateName="<Template Name>"
$Template=$SourceWeb.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($SourceWeb) | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $TemplateName }
$SourceWeb.Lists.Add($NewLibrary,$NewLibrary,$Template) > $null
```

Caveats:

1. Local SharePoint
2. Ran as credentials that already had sufficient permissions
3. SharePoint 2019
4. PowerShell 5.1